# exporting to csv file is not working in ie 11

Tags: javascript, csv

```
var link = document.createElement("a");    
link.id="lnkDwnldLnk";

//this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
document.body.appendChild(link);

var csv = CSV;  
blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' }); 
var csvUrl = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
var filename = "CCUDetail_";
$("#lnkDwnldLnk")
.attr({
    'download': filename,
    'href': csvUrl
}); 

$('#lnkDwnldLnk')[0].click();    
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Here it is showing script error that blob is undefined in ie 11.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for IE,

```
    var IEwindow = window.open();
    IEwindow.document.write('sep=,\r\n' + CSV);
    IEwindow.document.close();
    IEwindow.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".csv");
    IEwindow.close();
```

For more information i have written tutorial on that,
see - [Download JSON data in CSV format Cross Browser Support](http://code.ciphertrick.com/2014/12/07/download-json-data-in-csv-format-cross-browser-support/)

Hope this will be helpful for you.